# Obtener la menor fecha de una tabla relacionada C# entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

tengo una consulta, tengo dos modelos relacionados entre ellos.

```
    namespace Datos.DB
{
    [Table("Caes")]
    public class Cae
    {
        public long CaeId { get; set; }
        [Required]        
        public int CAETipoCFE { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public long CAENumero { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public long CAENumInicial { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public long CAENumFinal { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime CAEFechaVencimiento { get; set; }
        public int? CAEEspecial { get; set; }
        public int? CAECausalTipoDelCae { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool CAEFinalizado { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public long EmpresaId { get; set; }
        public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
        public virtual List<CaeParte> CaePartes { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Comprobante> Comprobantes { get; set; }

    }
    namespace Datos.DB
{
    [Table("CaePartes")]
    public class CaeParte
    {
        public long CaeParteId { get; set; }
        public long CAEParteNumIni { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public long CAEParteNumFin { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Int16 CAEParteCajaId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public long CAEParteUltimoAsignado { get; set; }
        public bool CAEParteAnulado { get; set; }
        public bool CAEParteFinalizado { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public long CaeId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual Cae Cae { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public long SucursalId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual Sucursal Sucursal { get; set; }
    }
}

    namespace Datos.Models
{
    public class datosCaeParte
    {
        public CaeParte ObtenerCaeActivo(int nroSucursal, int nroCaja, int tipocae)
        {
            using (DBModel dB = new DBModel())
            {
                var item = dB.CaePartes.Where(x => x.CAEParteAnulado == false && x.CAEParteFinalizado == false &&  
                                                   x.CAEParteCajaId == nroCaja && x.SucursalId == nroSucursal && x.Cae.CAETipoCFE == tipocae)
                            
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Cae.CAEFechaVencimiento).FirstOrDefault();

                return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que necesitaría es obtener el CaeParte o Default siempre que:

```
CAEParteAnulado == false && x.CAEParteFinalizado == false &&  
                                                   x.CAEParteCajaId == nroCaja && x.SucursalId == nroSucursal && x.Cae.CAETipoCFE == tipocae
```

pero siempre obteniendo la menor de las fechas CAEFechaVencimiento que está en la tabla relacionada CAE

En el ejemplo que realicé según los datos ingresados en la base de datos obtengo el CaeParte con ID 6 cuando en realidad debería obtener el 14 ya que pertenece a un cae cuya fecha de vencimiento es menor.

Les adjunto una captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pueden dar una mano se los agradecería muchísimo.
Saludos

Comment: En la consulta que expones fecha de vencimiento.. en el resultado de la consulta la tabla con fecha de vencimiento tienes 2022-10-20 que es mayor a 2020-12-18 cual debe seleccionar?

Comment: Siempre la menor debería ser

Answer (score 0):

me bastó con cambiar OrderByDescending por OrderBy .

Gracias Ger que con el razonamiento que me hiciste hacer se solucionó

```
namespace Datos.Models
{
    public class datosCaeParte
    {
        public CaeParte ObtenerCaeActivo(int nroSucursal, int nroCaja, int tipocae)
        {
            
            using (DBModel dB = new DBModel())
            {
                var item = dB.CaePartes.Where(x => x.CAEParteAnulado == false && x.CAEParteFinalizado == false &&  
                                                   x.CAEParteCajaId == nroCaja && x.SucursalId == nroSucursal && x.Cae.CAETipoCFE == tipocae)
                            
                            .OrderBy(x => x.Cae.CAEFechaVencimiento).FirstOrDefault();

                return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```